# configure double metaphone in french java apache

Tags: java, talend, metaphone

I want to use the function java apache DoubleMetaphoneEqual but with french language ? I'm using as routine in my talend job

Could you please tell me what should i add to my code ?
For the example
JAID MOHAMED, JAWAD MOHAMED gives true and in french is should be false

```
static DoubleMetaphone dd = new DoubleMetaphone();

 public static boolean resultat (final String value1, final String value2) 
 {
        return dd.isDoubleMetaphoneEqual(value1, value2,false);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard Apache implementation, this is not possible.
From the DoubleMetaphone Javadoc:

> Encodes a string into a double metaphone value. This Implementation is based on the algorithm by Lawrence Philips.

and from the [Metaphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) page on Wikipedia

> Metaphone is a phonetic algorithm, published by Lawrence Philips in 1990, for indexing words ***by their English pronunciation***

So it will not work for French

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer... Could you please give me an alternative that works in french ?